# Fixing javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate

Tags: java, android, https, ssl-certificate, android-volley

I am developing an android app that has to communicate with server over https  with self signed certificate (SSL/TLS1.2). I am also using Volley.

I am following [this](http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/using-android-volley-with-self-signed-certificate/) tutorial. Saved the .crt file, created key.bks in raw directory with `keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -file "cert.crt" -alias IntermediateCA -keystore "key.bks" -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath "bcprov-jdk16-146.jar" -storetype BKS -storepass blabla`
and so on.

When I am sending data to server, Response.ErrorListener() receives No peer certificate error.

Tried to send my json with Postman (of course, had to add the certificate)  -worked fine.

Manually installed the certificate on my android device - worked fine

How can I make it work?

Comment: Dora, Am also facing the same problem. Please let me know once you got a solution.

Comment: @OMG , I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fought a lot with this problem. 
It appeared that the server I was sending to has a virtual host (hosted on GAE). On Android 5.0 this issue is solved, but bellow Android 5.0 you have to add [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) support yourself. 
Here is an explanation of this problem http://blog.dev001.net/post/67082904181/android-using-sni-and-tlsv1-2-with-apache.

So to make my code work I had to change SslSocketFactory class from the tutorial. It did the magic.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;

import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;


import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory;
import android.os.Build;


 class SslSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

     InputStream mkeyStore;
     String mkeyStorePassword;

     public SslSocketFactory(InputStream keyStore, String keyStorePassword) throws KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException{
         super(null);
         mkeyStore=keyStore;
         mkeyStorePassword=keyStorePassword;

     }



      @Override
      public Socket connectSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort, HttpParams params) throws IOException {
          return null;
      }

      @Override
      public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
          return null;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isSecure(Socket s) throws IllegalArgumentException {
          if (s instanceof SSLSocket) {
              return ((SSLSocket) s).isConnected();
          }
          return false;
      }

      @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
      @Override
      public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
          SSLSocket sslSocket = null;


              if (autoClose) {
                  socket.close();
              }


                 SSLCertificateSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = (SSLCertificateSocketFactory) SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getDefault(0, null);


              try {
                sslSocketFactory.setTrustManagers(new TrustManager[] { new SsX509TrustManager( mkeyStore, mkeyStorePassword) });
            } catch (GeneralSecurityException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }



              sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(InetAddress.getByName(host), port);

              sslSocket.setEnabledProtocols(sslSocket.getSupportedProtocols());

              if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {

                  sslSocketFactory.setHostname(sslSocket, host);
              } else {

                  try {
                      java.lang.reflect.Method setHostnameMethod = sslSocket.getClass().getMethod("setHostname", String.class);
                      setHostnameMethod.invoke(sslSocket, host);
                  } catch (Exception e) {

                  }
              }


          return sslSocket;
      }

  }
```